# The Network icon lags behind

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8.1, icons

The Windows network icon in the system tray almost never shows the correct status right after the status changes.

Whenever I'm playing a windowed online game, or whenever I'm looking at the connection status on my modem/router's configuration page, those are noticing the lack of connectivity several seconds before the system tray icon changes.

Is there any way to have a more responsive network icon?

I have this problem on windows 8.1 but I had the same in windows 7

Comment: If you are using the same NIC in 8.1 as you were using in 7, it's probably a driver issue.

Comment: @spikey_richie If you're talking about the computer's network board it happened both on my now-dead laptop, running win7, and on this old PC, running 8.1. So, two different drivers (and boards).

Comment: The moment your router says 'connected' isn't always the same moment your PC can access the internet..... hense there maybe a delay.

Comment: @djsmiley2k when the router says "connected" I can command the online game to try connecting again, and I'm online again (game working, online opponent's actions getting to my system) before Windows acknowledges it. Also, no connection (sites don't refresh) and windows still tells me it's all ok, games tell me they're trying to reconnect, router properly says "disconnected".